# Creating Custom Pagination Design with MUI Pagination Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I modify the MUI(Material-UI) Pagination component in React to display a custom format like `<prev>`1 / 20`<next>` instead of the default pagination format.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
<Pagination
 count={20}
 renderItem={(item) => (
   <PaginationItem
     components={{
       last: (props) => <button {...props}>Last</button>,
       next: (props) => <button {...props}>Next</button>,
       first: (props) => <button {...props}>First</button>,
       previous: (props) => <button {...props}>Previous</button>,
     }}
    {...item}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define PaginationItem individually by applying condition for 'First','Last','Previous,'Next' like this:-

```
  <Pagination
      count={20}
      renderItem={(item) => {
        if (item.type === 'page') {
          return (
            <PaginationItem
              component="div"
              {...item}/>
          );
        }

        if (item.type === 'previous') {
          return (
            <PaginationItem
              component="div"
              {...item}>
              &lt;prev
            </PaginationItem>
          );
        }

        if (item.type === 'next') {
          return (
            <PaginationItem
              component="div"
              {...item}>
              next&gt;
            </PaginationItem>
          );
        }
        if (item.type === 'first') {
          return (
            <PaginationItem
              component="div"
              {...item}>
              First
            </PaginationItem>
          );
        }

        if (item.type === 'last') {
          return (
            <PaginationItem
              component="div"
              {...item}>
              Last
            </PaginationItem>
          );
        }

        return (
          <PaginationItem
            component="div"
            {...item} />
        );
      }}
    />
```